# Is thinking with language efficient?

Tags: language

First off, Im not sure, whether to put this into `Cognitive Science` or `Biology`. So sorry, if this is the wrong place.

I wondered, whether it is efficent to **think** with language (of course its efficient for communication). When Im thinking with long words, it takes longer than thinking with short words. Maybe thinking without words would be even faster?

So, do babies, who didnt learn think faster because they dont immediately try to find words for their thoughts to tell someone about them?

In our everyday life, we almost always need to talk to others about our thoughts. This leads to us thinking with these words instead of just thinking and then finding words for it. Its like writing a manuscript just from front to end instead of first brainstorming and collecting ideas.

**Main question:** Is it possible to think in a two-step process(and would it be more efficient)? First, thinking with `emotions`(or whatever you want to call it) and then finding `words` for that to spread your idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [CognitiveScience.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes.  And your "Milk tongue" greatly influences your cognitive style.  See Dennett, et al.